# Oracle query to fetch data in the form of a Tree

Tags: sql, database, oracle, hierarchical-query

I have a table with some data as follows

```
 Id | Title  | Category
 --  -----     --------
  1   Beans    Food
  2   Pizza    Food
  3   SQL      Book
  4   Avatar   Movie
  5   Oracle   Book
```

I would like to organize this kind of table data in the form of a TREE
with root node as Category.

```
Food
  Beans
  Pizza
Book
  SQL
  Oracle
Movie
  Avatar
```

Could you suggest a hierarchical query.
I tried few, but could not get the desired result.

**UPDATE** [realspirituals](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2772061/realspirituals)

Setup a fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10add/4/0), if you want to try

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle and post what you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be one solution

```
with tab as (select distinct category title, null parent from test
          union all 
         select title, category from test)
select lpad(' ', (level * 2 - 1), '-' ) ||  title as title
  from tab
  start with parent is null
connect by prior title = parent;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10add/13)

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT CASE
  WHEN title IS NULL THEN category
  ELSE '- ' || title
END category_title
FROM (
  SELECT title, category FROM table
  union all
  SELECT DISTINCT NULL title, category from table
) t
ORDER BY category, title NULLS FIRST
```